# Two REGEX operations with only one expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How to execute a series of actions to clean this string..

- Removing everything that comes after symbol `-` like `00058-541 = 00058`
- add zeros for the zip codes that arent 5 digits like `58 = 00058 OR 9542 = 09542`

data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Zip" : [501 , 38, 15 , 50501 , 80501 , 50501-514 , 85401-141 ]
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: @AMC sorry, I had to jump in a work call. Btw do you know  why I got down voted?

Comment: _Btw do you know why I got down voted?_ Yes, because Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I don’t get it, what’s wrong in not knowing how to solve a problem and asking for help. Everybody get the choice to answer or not. The question was organized and well asked as following the criteria, anyways..

Comment: _I don’t get it, what’s wrong in not knowing how to solve a problem and asking for help._ I never said there was. _Everybody get the choice to answer or not._ Eh, that doesn't seem like a great argument to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

you can use `str.replace` and `zfill` to get your desired result:

```
df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].astype(str).str.replace('-\d+','').str.zfill(5)

---

print(df)

       Zip
0    00501
1    00038
2    00015
3    50501
4    80501
5    50501
6    85401
```

Comment: So it works for insert the zeros, but I want DELETE everything that goes after this ```-``` like ```00058-541 = 00058 ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.apply()`/`.map()` with `str.split` and `str.format`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "Zip" : ['501' , '38', '15' , '50501' , '80501' , '50501-514' , '85401-141' ]})

df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].apply(lambda x: '{:0>5}'.format(x.split('-')[0])) # or .map()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Zip
0  00501
1  00038
2  00015
3  50501
4  80501
5  50501
6  85401
```

---

EDIT: Version with f-strings:

```
df['Zip'] = df['Zip'].map(lambda x: f"{x.split('-')[0]:0>5}")
```

Comment: It’s a minor thing, but you can use `.map()` instead of `.apply()`.

Comment: @AMC Thanks, I added comment in the answer.

Comment: Oh and I hadn’t noticed you’re not using f-strings, why is that?

Comment: @AMC I used it in the past, but many people here on SO used ancient versions of Python - so I use `.format()` as fail-safe alternative